# Passing Object between Android Service and Android Application

Tags: android, android-service

I want to be able to communicate between an Android Service which can communicate (send and receive object) with a different Android Application which is just displaying the objects it is receiving from the service or sending object back to the service.

All i found so far is communication between Activities in one single bundle, but i want to create a new Application with its own package that can receive object from the service.

Is that possible? How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send objects between applications unless they can be serialized to a byte stream. You can do that either by implementing `Serializable` or `Parcelable`. Then you can just put the object in an `Intent` as an extra.